# How can I make my social media bar zoom in and out at the same time my mouse wheel scroll does?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hello everybody I just started learning HTML and CSS to make my own page from scratch so, for this thread I just need some assistance with the social media bar, essentially what I need is just to make the bar capable of zooming in and out following the mouse wheel scroll of user, meaning that I won't have situations like this: [image: situations like this]

It should look like this instead (edited on paint):[image: situations expected]

here it's the code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Community Impact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="community-impactstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="s">
      <a href="index.html">Return to Index<i class="fas fa-hand-point-left"></i></a>
    </div>
    <h3>Noah Verner</h3>

   <header>
    </header>
    <main>
      <article>     
      </article>
      <aside>
      </aside>
    </main>
    <footer>Made by NOAH VERNER</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
    @font-face{
    src: url(Fonts/InputSerifCondensed-Regular.ttf);
    font-family: InputSerif;
}


*{
    font-family: InputSerif ;
}

body{
    background-color: #F5DC00;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    }

h3 {
    position: fixed;
    top: -20px ;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
   }

footer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
      }


/*Barra de iconos de redes sociales*/

.s{
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translate(-1070px,0px);
  }
.s a{
    color: #F5DC00;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: 1s;
    transition-property: transform;
    }
.s a:hover{
    transform: translate(200px, 0);
          }
.s i{
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    }
.s a:nth-child(1) i{
    color: #F5DC00;
                   }
```

*I know the code above doesn't contain all the 5 buttons, but I guess the solution could be applied to the "s" class rather than each button individually, and I tend to think the solution would be applied to the css file, but I'm a noob atm and can't figure it out*

any ideas?

Comment: So, just to clarify, you only want the icons to be visible (no matter what zoom level). The text of the buttons should not be visible? Or the other way around.

Comment: Never mind, I think I understand. You want the buttons to slide out like tabs when hovered, but remain tucked away (no matter the zoom) until then.

Comment: Yes, I just want those buttons to keep working regardless how far the mouse wheel scroll zooms in or out. Right now if I zoom out for instance these buttons stay in their current position but they should like dwarf just like the <h3> & <footer> do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're issue is that you are using the `transform` property to shift your element out of frame. A more robust way to do this would be to use the `left` property.

While we probably could find a way to do this in CSS, a more accurate way to do it would be using a touch of JavaScript - like so:

```js
//get all of our social tabs as an array
let socialElem = document.querySelectorAll('.social');

//loop through the array
socialElem.forEach((elem) => {
  //define our text element within the tab
  let text = elem.querySelector('.hidden');
  //get it's dimensions as a JavaScript object
  let textSize = text.getBoundingClientRect();
  /* now, using the dimensions object above, we can return the 'right' pixel value
  of our text element. If we scoot our tab in by the negative of that number it should
  perfectly hide our text without using transform.*/
  elem.style.left = -textSize.right + 'px';
  //we also add 'px' so that CSS can read it
})
```

```css
:root {
  /* set an accent color variable to make my life easier */
  --col-acc: #F5DC00;
}

body {
  /* reset default body styles */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  /* set the background color of the body to the accent color variable */
  background-color: var(--col-acc);
  /* set the font to something more appealing */
  font-family: "Segoe UI Variable Text", system-ui, ui-rounded, sans-serif;
}

.social {
  /* set the background color of the social tab to black */
  background-color: black;
  /* set the text color to our accent color variable */
  color: var(--col-acc);
  /* resize the tab to be the size of it's content */
  width: max-content;
  /* round the right side */
  border-radius: 0 32px 32px 0;
  /* fix the tab (absolute would also work here if you don't care about it staying put when scrolling up and down on the page) */
  position: fixed;
  /* center it vertically (could be applied to a parent/containter for multiple tabs) */
  top: 50%;
  /* set it to the left side of the screen */
  left: 0;
  /* center it just a little more vertically */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
  /* set the transition to the left property with a duration of 0.5 seconds */
  transition: left 0.5s;
}
.social a {
  /* give the anchor tag a display of block so we can resize it */
  display: block;
  /* override the color with our accent color*/
  color: var(--col-acc);
  /* remove the underline */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* beef up the font a little */
  font-weight: 500;
  /* make the font bigger */
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* add some padding to our tab */
  padding: 8px 24px;
}
.social:hover, .social:focus-within {
  /* on hover (or focus for accesability) set the left position to 0
  I set this property to "important" becase the JavaScript is setting the right value to 0
  in the elment styles (which normally overrides the stylesheet), so the important here
  re-overrides the elment style, if that makes sense*/
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="hidden">Social</span> 
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow it works pretty well on Snippet! Just to confirm, is the first chunk of code a JS file, the second a CSS file, and the last one a HTML file?

Comment: That's correct. I think that's how Stack always sets them up, I wish it was more clear where the sections began and ended.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a scroll effect where you take the ***scrollY*** and sum it with the boundingClientRect position of the element ***left*** and then add some constraints for the unit length in pixels within conditionals. Track the ***up*** and ***down*** scroll direction and add those to the conditionals for the in and out slide of the social icon and containing text.

```js
const socials = document.querySelectorAll('.socials')
let lastScroll = 0;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  let value = window.scrollY
  let output = ''
  let currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  if (currentScroll > 0 && lastScroll <= currentScroll) {
    lastScroll = currentScroll
    output = "down"
  } else {
    lastScroll = currentScroll
    output = "up"
  }
  socials.forEach(icon => {
    let rect = icon.getBoundingClientRect()
    rect.left < -16 && output === "down" ?
      icon.style.left = `${rect.left + value * 0.15}px` :
    rect.left > -16 && output === "down" ?
      icon.style.left = `0px` : 
    rect.left > "-192" && output === "up" ?
      icon.style.left = `${rect.left - value * 0.15}px` :
    rect.left < "-192" && output === "up" ?
      icon.style.left = `-192px` : null
  })
})
```

```css
body * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  height: 300vh;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

.socials {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 15rem;
  height: auto;
  background: green;
  color: limegreen;
  border-top-right-radius: 2rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  left: -12rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="socials">
    Follow me on Rumble
    <img src="https://img.utdstc.com/icon/01c/903/01c9032ef30ddf7a9f0346ce3a77b92fd5602e34818f25603962012d2792fab6:200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! this one works well too! but as my page is not going to have a scroll bar this solution can't be applied, however if needed in the future I would definitely take it in consideration, upvoted :)

Comment: Oh, btw excuse me If I didn't make myself understand, when I typed that the social media bar had to follow the zooming of the mouse wheel scroll, I meant that the user had to first press Ctrl key and then scroll using the wheel scroll of his/her mouse for zooming in or out my page.

Comment: Ahh okay, I see you have what you needed best and happy coding ;)

Comment: This is a super creative application! Really like what you did with this.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody, I just found out another solution for my issue, which is even more simple and easy (thanks @calvin-bonner for making me realize it):

In my CSS file: I just typed this:

```
.s{
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    left: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translate(-82.5%);

  }
```

AS you can see, I only added `left: 0;` and changed `transform: translate(-1070px,0px);` to `transform: translate(-82.5%);`, and now it works pretty well just as I expected

*(Actual screenshot of my index after applying my simple solution above)*
[image: simple solution]

> *Note: I think this solution works well because I'm not using nor*
> *planning to add a scroll bar on my website*

Comment: This is great. The only (potential) issue I see is that without JavaScript, it is much more difficult to say how much of the tab should be obscured. On different devices, display sizes, and system fonts, different amounts may need to be shown or hidden. JavaScript eliminates all of that concern by getting the true width of the hidden element and adjusting accordingly.